# Understanding a PWM based controller circuit for a nichrome heater

Tags: pwm, control-circuit

I have been working on designing a PWM based control circuit for a nichrome heating element in a hot air oven. I have attached a picture of the circuit I have been working on. As far as my understanding goes, the coil heats up according to Joule heating and obeys the relation

> *m s ΔT = I^2 R t*

where 'm' is the mass of my nichrome coil, 's' is it's specific heat, ΔT is the change in temperature from ambient temperature, 'I' is the average current through my circuit, 'R' is the resistance of my coil and 't' is the time for which the circuit operates. I hope I'm right about this.
[image]

I've simulated this circuit on LT spice and obtained transient current across my load.
[image]
While this waveform is desirable, I am not sure about the specifications of my components. It would be great if I can get some guidance on how to pick my components to get a desirable output (generally, hot air ovens can heat up to 300°C). Moreover, changing the duty cycle of my PWM pulse does not show much of a difference in my output current (I guess this would also be a consequence of me not choosing my components accordingly).

Another problem I face is that according to the relation mentioned above, If I increase the duration of my circuit operation 't', ΔT would keep increasing when my circuit is supposed to maintain a constant temperature. I don't really understand the logic there.

Since I'm sort of new to designing circuits, I would appreciate any help or comments on my situation here.

Comment: Your equation does not include radiation or conduction losses. It would only work for transient big load steps, not for steady state where mass does not matter.

Comment: What is L1 doing in there?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @winny's comment. The equation is correct if heat losses are small. The problem is that you're not trying to heat the wire - you're trying to heat the air so losses have to be high.

Typical industrial heating controls would use a heater element with twice the power rating required to maintain the desired temperature. i.e., Once temperature has been achieved it can be maintained with about 50% power or so. This gives a good trade-off between time to reach operating temperature and not so much power that steady control is difficult to maintain. (Too much power would be like trying to drive a high-powered sports car in a 30 kph zone.)

In most applications the heating time constant is long enough that we can control power using proportional time control. It's the same as PWM but at a much lower rate - maybe on-off cycles of several seconds to several minutes. This works particularly well for AC control using TRIACs and zero-cross SSRs (solid-state relays).

[image]

*Figure 1. Proportional control for an AC supply using zero-cross TRIAC. Image source: [LEDnique](http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-triacs-zero-cross-work/).*

You can do the same thing with a DC load. L1 isn't required. You can just switch the DC on and off using M1.